# Find the limit of the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Help me please, I don't know if I should treat this sequence as a series.
Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since $$1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2},$$ we have that $$x_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}.$$

Can you solve it from here?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** You probably know a simple formula for $1+2+3+\cdots+n$.

**Remark:**  The sequence $(x_n)$ is a sequence. And the terms are sums.

But one should not waste too much thought on *classification*. We have a concrete problem here; What happens to $\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2}$ as $n$ gets huge?

Answer (score 4):

**Another Hint**: Rewrite the limit as:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[ \frac{1}{n}[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n}+...+\frac{n}{n}]]$$
Can you relate this to $\int_0^1 x dx$ ?